# style react component on click

Tags: reactjs, components, styling

so i have this simple divs of names:

i just want to press on one of them and get a background color of green and when pressing on another one the first one will be canceled so just one will be colored at a time. what i simply need is inline style or i don't know i'm stuck.

first.js:

import React from 'react';

```
function SidebarComponents({name,title,selected,onSelect}) {

    const style={
        cursor: "pointer"
    };

    const classes = {
        selected: {
          backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
        }
      }

    return (
        <div 
            name={name}
            title = {title}
            style={style}
        >
           {name}
        </div>
    )

}
export default SidebarComponents;
```

second.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SidebarComponents from "../SidebarComponents/SidebarComponents";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../Sidebar1/Sidebar.css';

function Sidebar({ onChange }) {
  const [selectedComponent, setSelectedComponent] = useState({
    componentsName: [
      { name: "John Smith", title: "John Smith" },
      { name: "Male, 26 years old", title: "Gender and age" },
      { name: "john", title: "Alerts" },
      { name: "claude", title: "Recent" },
      { name: "edward", title: "Blood pressure" },
      { name: "mira", title: "Body weight" },
      { name: "alex", title: "Glucose" },
      { name: "zac", title: "SPO2" }
    ]
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedComponent.componentsName.map(component => {
        return (
            <div className="row align-items-start sidebar-components">
                <div className="col">
                    <SidebarComponents 
                    name={component.name} 
                    title={component.title} 
                    />
                </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: use that div name to make a classname combo like className={selectedDiv == 'div1'?'active' : ' '}. And give background color to that active class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Sidebar:

```
const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = useState(null);
//...
<SidebarComponents 
  name={component.name} 
  title={component.title}
  selected={component.name === selectedName}
  onSelect={setSelectedName}
/>
```

on SidebarComponents:

```
const selectedClassName = selected ? 'selected' : '';

//...

<div 
  name={name}
  title={title}
  style={style}
  className={`sidebar ${selectedClassName}`} //you must add sidebar and selected classes to your styles
  onClick={() => onSelect(name)}
>
  {name}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add key attribute to div, inside the map.
2. Handel onClick event, to store the selected element index/value in your state.
3. Apply style using conditional rendering of className.

second.js

```js
<div>
  {selectedComponent.componentsName.map((component, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index} onClick={() => handelOnClick(index)} className="row align-items-start sidebar-components">
        <div className="col">
          <SidebarComponents 
            name={component.name} 
            title={component.title} 
            className={selectedIndex === index ? 'highlight' : ''}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

1. As you are rendering text in first.js no need to use div wrapper, use 'p', 'span' tag
2. In second.js instead of iterating entire div block, use ul li